# Generate random even number in range [m, n]

Tags: c, random

I was looking for C code to generate a set of random even number in range `[start, end]`. I tried,

```
int random = ((start + rand() % (end - start) / 2)) * 2;
```

This won't work, for example if the range is [0, 4], both 0 & 4 included

```
int random = (0 + rand() % (4 - 0) / 2) * 2
=> (rand() % 2) * 2
=> 0, 2, ... (never includes 4) but expectation = 0, 2, 4 ...
```

On the other hands if I use,

```
int random = ((start + rand() % (end - start) / 2) + 1) * 2;
```

This won't work, for example,

```
int random = (0 + (rand() % (4 - 0) / 2) + 1) * 2
=> ((rand() % 4 / 2) + 1) * 2
=> 2, 4,  ... (never includes 0) but expectation = 0, 2, 4 ...
```

Any clue? how to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You complicated it too much. Since you're using `rand()` and the modulo operator, I'm assuming that you will not be using this for cryptographic or security purposes, but as a simple even number generator.

The formula I have found for generating a random even number in the range of [0, 2n] is to use

```
s = (rand() % (n + 1)) * 2
```

An example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, s;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s = (rand() % 3) * 2;
        printf("%d ", s);
    }
}
```

And it gave me the following output:

```
2 2 0 2 4 2 2 0 0 2 4 2 4 2 4 2 0 0 2 2 4 4 0 0 4 4 4 2 2 2 4 0 0 0 4 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 4 4 2 4 4 4 0 4 2 2 4 4 0 4 4 2 2 0 0 4 0 4 4 2 0 2 4 0 0 0 0 4 0 4 4 0 4 2 0 0 4 4 0 0 4 4 2 0 0 4 0 2 2 2 0 0 4 0 2 4 2
```

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Where did you get 3 for range [0,4] ?

Comment: what would be generalised formula for range [m,n]?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan: 3 is the number of even integers in [0, 4]. Generally, in [a, b], for non-negative a and b, there are `b/2 - (a+1)/2 + 1` even integers (using integer arithmetic, so division truncates to an integer).

Comment: the generalized formula is still complicated. thankd Ptr n Raf

Answer (score 2):

`rand() % x` will generate a number in the range `[0,x)` so if you want the range `[0,x]` then use `rand() % (x+1)`

> Common notation for ranges is to use `[]` for inclusive and `()` for exclusive, so `[a,b)` would be a range such that a is included but not b.

So in your case, just use `(rand() % 3)*2` to get random numbers among `{0,2,4}`

If you want even numbers in the range `[m,n]`, then use `((m/2) + rand() % ((n-m+2)/2))*2`

Comment: where did you get 3 for range [0, 4]?

Comment: 3 will give you 0,1 and 2. Multiply by 2 and get 0, 2 and 4.

Comment: what will be in place of 3 when range is [m, n]?

Comment: You cannot simply replace the 3 to do that. You'll have to fix an offset for that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not trust in the mod operator for random numbers. I prefer

```
start + ((1 + stop - start) * rand())
         / (1 + RAND_MAX)
```

which only relies on the distribution of `rand()` in the interval
`[0, .. , RAND_MAX]` and not on any distribution of `rand()%n` in the 
interval `[0, .. , n-1]`.

Note: If you use this expression you should add appropriate casts to avoid multiplication overflow.

Note also 
ISO/IEC 9899:201x (p.346):

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just and-out the low bit, which makes it even:

```
n= (rand()%N)&(-2);
```

and to use a start/stop (a range), the values can be offset:

```
int n, start= 5, stop= 20+1;
n= ((rand()%(stop-start))+start)&(-2);
```

The latter calculation generates a random number between 0 and RAND_MAX (this value is library-dependent, but is guaranteed to be at least 32767).

If the stop value must be included in the range of generated numbers, then add 1 to the stop value.

It takes that value modulo the stop value *plus* the start value, and then adds the start value. The value is now within the range of [start, stop]. As only even numbers are required, the low bit is anded-out because even numbers start at 2.

The anding-out is performed by generating a mask of all 1's, except the lowest bit. As -1 is all 1's (`0xFFF...FFFFF`), -2 is all 1's except this low bit (`0xFFF...FFFFE`). Next the bitwise `AND` operation (&) is perfomed with this mask and the number is now in the range [start,stop]. QED.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote (as this works)?

Comment: I guess it's because it seems very overkill to teach bit manipulation in this situation. It's just confusing even if it is correct.

Comment: I guess a 10.8K OP knows about bit manipulation, so what's the overkill?

Comment: I'm just guessing. One could also argue that someone hackish enough to know how to use bit manipulation for various things also knows how to generate random numbers within a range. ;)

Comment: It would be best if you could elaborate your answer. Thanks for the time @PaulOgilvie

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, did so, but it is just saying something that would be obvious to anyone a) knowing C and b) knowing their math.

Comment: `&(-2)` is not fully portable, since the C standard permits one’s complement and sign-magnitude representations. Also, the parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, [start,stop] fixed. A way to generate the mask in 1-complement's implementations would be to specify the mask like `0xFFFFFFFE` but how to cope with different integer widths on different platforms? (any suggestion?)

Comment: Since the value is positive, you could use `& -2u`. (This results in promoting `int` to `unsigned int`. If the number were negative, the result would overflow when converted back to `int`, which runs afoul of undefined behavior.) This will “work,” however, it is preferable to use the high bits of `rand` rather than the low bits due to problems in legacy implementations of `rand`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Erics comment is a perfect example of why it is a good idea to avoid overly hackish stuff. Bit manipulation could seem easy, but you did a mistake. I have to admit that I didn't spot it either, but nevertheless, your answer is not 100% correct at the moment. That may also be a reason for downvotes.